# Can I retract a reopen vote?

Tags: support, vote-to-reopen

I just went through the Reopen Votes review queue and found [this question (A)](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/100896/humorous-story-about-toilet-paper-perforations-leading-to-the-creation-nothing?lq=1), which is currently closed as a dupe of [this question (B)](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/95453/story-about-a-man-who-discovers-the-power-of-nothing), which is currently closed as "unclear what you're asking". Had I known all this at the start, I would've voted to reopen A and leave B closed as the poorer - albeit older - of the two duplicate questions. But I came across B first and voted to reopen it (the text of the question doesn't say, but the tags do), then came across A and voted to reopen that too (having been told the site policy on closing story ID questions as dupes).

<sub>I'm just saying all that so the mods know why I voted to reopen both and don't ban me from the review queues on this basis. Irrelevant backstory aside...</sub>

### Is there a way I can retract a reopen vote?

Retracting close votes is easy - just click on the 'close' button as if you're voting to close again, but then you can 'Retract Close Vote' instead of 'Vote to Close'. But when I click on the 'reopen' button as if I'm voting to reopen again, all I get is an error message saying 'you have already voted to reopn'. Is there another way to do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Survey says no. There was a [feature request for this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/193061/ability-to-retract-reopen-delete-votes) posted on Meta.SE back in 2013, but there was no response from the StackExchange team.

[A related question posted earlier this year on Meta.SO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284239/undo-a-reopen-request) got a "no" answer from an SE employee:

> No, it is not currently possible to retract a reopen vote.
>
> However, your reopen vote will have bumped the question into the Reopen Votes queue. If reviewers choose to leave it closed, the aging process will begin immediately and your reopen vote will automatically expire after four days assuming no other reopen votes get cast.

The only thing you can do is hope that your vote [ages away](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136989/how-do-close-votes-age-away); per Shog9's answer to that question:

> [W]hen the aging task fires it just looks at every post that has at least 100 views where all outstanding close votes are older than 4 days, and every post where all outstanding close votes are older than 14 days [regardless of the view count](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250223/modernize-the-close-vote-aging-logic).